# Named and default arguments class arguments in Python

Tags: python, arguments, default, named

In PHP, I have to pass the arguments in the same order as the arguments are in the constructor.

Now, in Python, take

```
listbox = Listbox(root, yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
```

for example.

If I had passed yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set as the third argument and yscrollcommand was the second argument in the constructor, would I still be able to access scrollbar.set from yscrollcommand inside the listbox constructor?

I ask this because even though the arguments are not in the same order, with an equal sign they have a name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Named arguments don't have to be in order.

```
class xyz:
    def __init__ (self, a='1', b='2'):
        print a,b

xyz(b=3,a=4)
xyz(a=5,b=6)

>>4 3
>>5 6
```